# How to configure snmpsim to simulate multiple agents, each agent listening to different ip address and servers same object with some variations?

Tags: python, snmp, simulator

I'm using snmpsim-lextudio python project to simulate multiple SNMP agents, I want to achieve the following:

- Use only SNMP v1/v2c not v3.
- Community should be public
- All agents listen to port 161
- Each agent listens to different IP address.
- Each agent serves different data file. or same data file but change some objects based on agent address.
- For the same agent, some objects are with fixed value but are unique to the agent, some objects increase overtime and must be stored if agent is stopped.
- I prefer to run each agent in separate process, note that I'm using Windows.

How can I achieve that?

So far, I managed to run each agent from separate console using this command:

snmpsim-command-responder-lite --agent-udpv4-endpoint=127.0.0.1:161 --data-dir=.\data\0001

With different IP and data folder for each. But that's not ideal if I want to run 100s of agents!

Thanks

Ameen

Comment: You might take a look at https://www.pysnmp.com/snmpsim-control-plane/

Comment: The difference between an open-source and commercial SNMP simulator is the amount of effort for a scenario just like that. Google SNMP simulator for some offerings. Our customers routinely run thousands of agents with the characteristics you mention.